# Is there a function to replace part of string?

Tags: sqlite

- I have a Column Line_num

Line_Num

06-ZB-A23-475004-SHT1

10-ZB-A23-4750041-SHT2

2.5-ZB-A23-4750-SHT3

06-ZB-A23-475004-5H6-SHT13

- Result I want is

Line_Num

06-ZB-A23-475004

10-ZB-A23-4750041

2.5-ZB-A23-4750

06-ZB-A23-475004-5H6

I have used the below Code

UPDATE Filename
SET line_num = REPLACE(line_num, '-SHT*', '')
WHERE line_num like '%-SHT%';

But it does not work. can anyone help me with this.

UPDATE Filename
SET line_num = REPLACE(line_num, '-SHT*', '')
WHERE line_num like '%-SHT%';

Comment: * in replace just says replace * and not all characters after T. You should use a regular expression. Maybe this post can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877856/replace-a-part-of-a-string-with-regexp-in-sqlite3 . It seems there is actually no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
UPDATE Filename SET line_num = substr(line_num, 1, instr(line_num, '-SHT')-1) WHERE line_num like '%-SHT%';
```