# Partially replacing strings in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I wonder if I can do the following directly in SQL. I have a text-formatted column with values separated by `-`. So an example row value could look `1-42-9`. I want to make a selection such that each string in between the `-` is replaced by another according to some logic. As an example, let's say my logic says that each string equal to `42` should be replaced by `ABC` which would give me `1-ABC-9`. Can this be done in a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: You can consider using sql replace() function. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877856/replace-a-part-of-a-string-with-regexp-in-sqlite3)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Let's say a value looks like `1-11-111`. If I use replace, how do I distinguish between 1, 11, and 111?

Comment: You can replace -11- with -ABC-, for example

Comment: do you use SQLite? it has a very limited set of functions

Comment: @AlexYes, yes I do use SQLite for several reasons but I am aware of the limitations. Thanks for pointing that out though! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column contains a value like `'1-42-9'` and you want to search for `'42'` to replace with `'ABC'`, then you must take in account all cases like:

- `'42'` is at the beginning of the column
- `'42'` is in the middle of the column
- `'42'` is at the end of the column
- `'42'` is the only value of the column

These 4 cases can be handled with a more complicated but precise method:

```
select substr(
  replace('-' || col || '-', '-42-', '-ABC-'), 
  2,
  length(replace('-' || col || '-', '-42-', '-ABC-')) - 2
) NewCol
from tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qhyKqDamVP7u1vMgcmTabB/2).
For these values:

```
create table tablename (col TEXT);
insert into tablename (col) values
('1-42-9'),
('42-1-9'),
('9-1-42'),
('42'),
('1-100-9');
```

The results are:

```
| NewCol  |
| ------- |
| 1-ABC-9 |
| ABC-1-9 |
| 9-1-ABC |
| ABC     |
| 1-100-9 |
```

Comment: This is interesting. How would you adjust the code to a situation where there are four numbers in each row? E.g. `1-32-5-61`? And how would you add several conditions in one go? So that for example 1s are replaced with A, 32s with B etc. Worth to mention is that there is no situation where there is only a single value in each row. All rows have the format `number-number-number-number`and the numbers are either 1 or 2-digit numbers. Thanks.

Comment: The code works for any number of numbers and it does not matter if they are 1 or 2 digits or more, if you want 1 replacement. For 2 or more replacements at the same time it becomes complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Using `substring` and `case`, you can do something like the following:

```
select case when '1-42-9' like '%-42-%'
then replace('1-42-9','-42-', '-ABC-' )
else '1-42-9' end
```

Instead of the static value of `'1-42-9'`, you need to write the column name.

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be done in a SELECT statement?

Yes, you can use the [replace function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace)

To do just do the 1 replace you could use :-

```
SELECT replace(mycolumn,'-42-','ABC') AS mycolumn FROM mytable;
```

A working example that demonstrates this simple singular replacement is :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (mycolumn);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('1-42-9'),('1429'); -- add some data (one row to be changed, the other not to be changed)
SELECT replace(mycolumn,'-42-','ABC') AS mycolumn FROM mytable; -- Do the replace maintaing the column name
```

This results in :-

[image]

If you wanted a more complex replacement say replacing two items you could use nested replaces , noting that this can be quite tedious as the replacement order is relevant for example to replace -9 with XYZ and -42- with ABC so that 1-42-9 become 1ABCXYZ then you could use :-

```
SELECT replace(replace(mycolumn,'-9','-XYZ'),'-42-','ABC') AS mycolumn FROM mytable;
```

If you wanted multiple replacements of which only 1 would be done say -42- is replaced with ABC or -43- with DEF or -44- with GHI then you could use a CASE WHEN THEN END construct along the lines of :-

```
SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN instr(mycolumn,'-42-') THEN replace(mycolumn,'-42-','ABC')
      WHEN instr(mycolumn,'-43-') THEN replace(mycolumn,'-43-','DEF')
      WHEN instr(mycolumn,'-44-') THEN replace(mycolumn,'-44-','GHI')
      ELSE mycolumn
  END AS mycolumn
FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic solution that is SQLite compatible would be to nest substr and instr functions to split the list into elements and then apply replacement logic to elements.

For a table `strings` that has columns `id` with values `'1-42-9'`, `'777-5-21'` and `'7-55-123'` (so you're sure it works with variable lengths of the elements and covers `1` vs `111` case), it would be:

```
SELECT
 input 
,first_element || '-' ||
 CASE second_element 
    WHEN '42' THEN 'ABC'
    WHEN '5' THEN 'DEF'
    ELSE second_element
 END || '-' ||
 third_element as output
FROM (
    select 
    id as input,
    substr(
      id,
      1,
      instr(id,'-')-1
    ) as first_element,             
    substr(
      substr(id,instr(id,'-')+1,100),
      1,
      instr(substr(id,instr(id,'-')+1,100),'-')-1
    ) as second_element
    ,substr(
      substr(id,instr(id,'-')+1,100),
      instr(substr(id,instr(id,'-')+1,100),'-')+1,
      100
    ) as third_element
    from strings
) t
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tBK6EA2KTKG3id7ghvvet2/1)

(might be more beautiful but it's working:))

this works only for string lists that have 3 elements separated by dashes

if you want to replace a certain element at any position just apply the same CASE statement to `first_element` and `third_element`

also, you can do simply this:

`replace('-'||id||'-','-42-','-ABC-')` - if you wrap your strings into an additional pair of dashes you would be able to search for `42` regardless of its position (start, middle, end)