# How can I do REGEXP_REPLACE in SQLAlchemy with SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, regexp-replace

I have a Postgres-backed website, and use `REGEXP_REPLACE`  to replace the first instance of a value in some columns. This is fine. The problem comes where I need to run CI, and for one reason and another (limitations of Github Actions and Windows VMs), I can't use Postgres in my tests.

Choosing SQLite produced a few test failures, and I realised that SQLite doesn't have `REGEXP_REPLACE` built in.

```
    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: regexp_replace
E       [SQL: SELECT job_site.created_at AS job_site_created_at, ..., job_site.neighborhood_id AS job_site_neighborhood_id 
E       FROM job_site 
E       WHERE regexp_replace(job_site.name, ?, ?) = ?]
E       [parameters: (' - ', ':', 'BGS:NEEA - 1894 - 05700 Brown Islands Suite 681')]
E       (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

How can I add this function to SQLite in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to register `regexp_replace` as a `GenericFunction` ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.GenericFunction)), and add a dialect-specific compiler ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/compiler.html)) to be used when running with the SQLite engine.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import GenericFunction


class regexp_replace(GenericFunction):
    type = String
    identifier = "regexp_replace"


@compiles(regexp_replace, "sqlite")
def visit_regexp_replace(element, compiler, **kw):
    column, pattern, replacement = list(element.clauses)
    return (
        f"SUBSTR({column}, 0, INSTR ({column}, '{pattern.value}')) "
        f"|| '{replacement.value}' "
        f"|| SUBSTR({column}, INSTR ({column}, '{pattern.value}') + LENGTH('{pattern.value}'))"
    )
```

It is also possible to use the SQLite C extension as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44586265/1706564), but I didn't look into making that work.

Comment: One more available technique is to register a Python function as `regexp_replace` in SQLite: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function. That'd allow you to perform an actual regexp replace.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I did see that in the docs, but wasn't clear where/when I would register that using SQLAlchemy

Comment: One option is to do it when a DB-API connection is created. There's an example of that in the part that covers enabling foreign key checks in SQLite: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support.