# Export Contacts from Apple Address Book Database

Tags: macos, sqlite, contacts

Apple stores Address Book Data in a local `sqlite3` databse. I want to export the name and number in a clean and consistent format for all contacts

The database is located in:  `/Users/kellygold/Library/Application\ Support/AddressBook/Sources/<RANDOMSTRING>/AddressBook-v22.abcddb` where RANDOMSTRING is a generated file name

Inside the DB there is a table `ZABCDPHONENUMBER` with field `ZFULLNUMBER` but the values are not stored consistently

[image: ZFULLNUMBER]

NOTE the different formats: `(111) 222-3333, +12223334444, 1112223333, +1 (222) 333-4444`. Some numbers appear in only one format, some numbers have multiple rows with multiple formats for same contact

**Query to produce this:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ZABCDRECORD.ZFIRSTNAME [FIRST NAME],
    ZABCDRECORD.ZLASTNAME [LAST NAME],
    ZABCDPHONENUMBER.ZFULLNUMBER [FULL NUMBER]
FROM
    ZABCDRECORD
    LEFT JOIN ZABCDPHONENUMBER ON ZABCDRECORD.Z_PK = ZABCDPHONENUMBER.ZOWNER
ORDER BY
    ZABCDRECORD.ZLASTNAME,
    ZABCDRECORD.ZFIRSTNAME,
    ZABCDPHONENUMBER.ZORDERINGINDEX ASC
```

**Desired output flat with preceeding country code optional:**

```
FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, FULL NUMBER
asdf, fghj, 2223334444
bbbb, cccc, 12223334444
```

Currently I process the data by exporting the SQLITE query as JSON and running this very hacky solution
`cat adbExport.json| jq '.[] | select(.["FULL NUMBER"] != null)' | sed 's/+//g'\ | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/-//g' | sed 's/(//g'| sed 's/)//g' | jq '{FIRSTNAME: .FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME: .LASTNAME, FULLNUMBER: ("+1"+ .FULLNUMBER)}' | sed 's/+11/+1/g' > cleanContacts.json`

This produces valid JSON which I can use. (data obfuscated for security)

```
...
{
  "FIRSTNAME": "AnXXX",
  "LASTNAME": "ZuckXXX",
  "FULLNUMBER": "2068901111"
}
{
  "FIRSTNAME": "Nick",
  "LASTNAME": "fromHay",
  "FULLNUMBER": "262443XXXX"
}
...
```

**How can I do this directly from the Database query?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sqlite3 ~/Library/"Application Support"/AddressBook/Sources/*/AddressBook-v22.abcddb<<EOF
.mode json
SELECT DISTINCT
    ZABCDRECORD.ZFIRSTNAME [FIRST NAME],
    ZABCDRECORD.ZLASTNAME [LAST NAME],
    ZABCDPHONENUMBER.ZFULLNUMBER [FULL NUMBER]
FROM
    ZABCDRECORD
    LEFT JOIN ZABCDPHONENUMBER ON ZABCDRECORD.Z_PK = ZABCDPHONENUMBER.ZOWNER
ORDER BY
    ZABCDRECORD.ZLASTNAME,
    ZABCDRECORD.ZFIRSTNAME,
    ZABCDPHONENUMBER.ZORDERINGINDEX ASC;
EOF
```

The result I get is :

```
[{"FIRST NAME":null,"LAST NAME":null,"FULL NUMBER":null},
{"FIRST NAME":"Philippe","LAST NAME":"surname","FULL NUMBER":"+188888888"}]
```

*Update*

You list of commands can be done with a single call of jq :

```
jq '.[]["FULL NUMBER"] |= gsub("[ ()+]";"")' adbExport.json
```

You can also do it in SQL with an extension : [replace a part of a string with REGEXP in sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877856/replace-a-part-of-a-string-with-regexp-in-sqlite3)

Comment: No dice. I still get multiple formats in the `FULL NUMBER` column

Comment: Are you sure you put `.mode json` as in my answer ?

Comment: yeah, sorry. the JSON output works fine, but my result is


`{"FIRST NAME":"Sari","LAST NAME":"Younan","FULL NUMBER":"72********"},
{"FIRST NAME":"Ni**","LAST NAME":"Ze***","FULL NUMBER":"+1 (***) 760-****"},
{"FIRST NAME":"P****r","LAST NAME":"****em","FULL NUMBER":"(***) ***-****"},` Note the different formats for the phone number. Know any way to only get integers for that?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a good way to manipulate the data in the fields form the query. Instead. Here is some python to solve it cleaner than the bash above

```
def get_address_book(address_book_location):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(address_book_location)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT ZABCDRECORD.ZFIRSTNAME [FIRST NAME], ZABCDRECORD.ZLASTNAME [LAST NAME], ZABCDPHONENUMBER.ZFULLNUMBER [FULL NUMBER] FROM ZABCDRECORD LEFT JOIN ZABCDPHONENUMBER ON ZABCDRECORD.Z_PK = ZABCDPHONENUMBER.ZOWNER ORDER BY ZABCDRECORD.ZLASTNAME, ZABCDRECORD.ZFIRSTNAME, ZABCDPHONENUMBER.ZORDERINGINDEX ASC")
    result_set = cursor.fetchall()

    json_output = json.dumps([{"FIRST NAME": t[0], "LAST NAME": t[1], "FULL NUMBER": t[2]} for t in result_set])
    json_list = json.loads(json_output)
    conn.close()

    for obj in json_list:
        # Get the phone number from the object
        phone = obj["FULL NUMBER"]
        if phone is None:
            continue
        # Remove all non-numeric characters from the phone number
        phone = "".join([c for c in phone if c.isnumeric()])
        #if the phone number is 10 digits, add "+1" to the beginning, if it's 11 digits, add "+"
        if len(phone) == 10:
            phone = "+1" + phone
        elif len(phone) == 11:
            phone = "+" + phone
        # Add the phone number to the object
        obj["NUMBERCLEAN"] = phone
        

    new_json_output = json.dumps(json_list)
    return new_json_output
```