# Parse specific XML tag value

Tags: sql, xml, sqlite, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an SQLite 3.38.2 table that has XML tags in a column:

```
with cte(xml_tag) as (values 
  ('<Event time="Sat Apr 22 1:01:51.887" type="Debug" thread="2164: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="1" function="Geodatabase.Cursor" code="EndCursor">'), 
  ('<Event time="Sat Apr 22 1:01:51.883" type="Debug" thread="2164: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="23" function="Geodatabase.Cursor" code="EndCursor">'), 
  ('<Event time="Sat Apr 22 1:01:51.874" type="Debug" thread="2164: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="456" function="Geodatabase.Cursor" code="EndCursor">'), 
  ('<Event time="Sat Apr 22 1:01:51.846" type="Debug" thread="2164: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="7890" function="Geodatabase.Cursor" code="EndCursor">'))
select * from cte
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nNc_nNhs)

I want to extract the values from the `elapsed` tag as numbers:

```
elapsed
-------
      1
     23
    456
   7890
```

How can I extract the values from that XML tag using a SQL query?

Comment: Use the facilities of the language you're making sql queries from.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38877856/5841306) help you answer the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all `xml_tag`'s values contain the substring `'elapsed='` (only once) you can use string functions:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(xml_tag, INSTR(xml_tag, 'elapsed=') + LENGTH('elapsed=') + 1) + 0 AS elapsed
FROM cte;
```

By adding `0` to the extracted string it is implicitly converted to a number.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ukH0GTVf).